# Database connection succeeds for non-existent databases

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, connection-string

Looks like SQLite database connection doesn't actually try to open database connection when I call `Open()` function. Here's a simple test:

```
var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SQLite");
connection = factory.CreateConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = "data source=NonExistentDB.db3";
conn.Open();
```

The above code does not generate any kind of exception. Moreover, the connection state is `Open` after this. Is there a way to do "Test Connection" that would physically establish a connection with the database?

Comment: Run a `SELECT 1` query and see if it gets you a result?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

`connection.ConnectionString = "data source=NonExistentDB.db3;FailIfMissing=True"`

Without the last argument, it will simply create a new database if the file is not found.